# SQL statement greater issue

Tags: mysql, compare

I'm building a small gym training system and I'm currently having a problem with an SQL query. I need to get the names of all customers who are more than ten kilos heavier than their target weight. Here are my tables.

```
Person: PersonID | Name | DOB | Email | Gender    
Item: ItemID | Name | Portion | kCal | Fat    
Training: TrainingID | Person_ID | StartDate | StartWeight | TargetWeight | CurrentWeight
```

Now I can get the list of people who are heavier than their target weight, but I specifically need to receive customers who are more than 10 kg heavier than their target weight. I know it's probably basic but I just couldn't get my head around it for somehow. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select p.*
from person p
join training t on t.person_id = p.personid
where t.currentweight - t.targetweight > 10
```